# convergence behavior of $a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\left( \alpha+\frac 1n \right)^k$

Tags: calculus

$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\left( \alpha+\frac 1n \right)^k \quad \alpha\in (0,1)$$
I have to analyze the convergence behavior of this sequence. If applicable I have to determine the limit!

(I know it is coupled with "$e$", but $a \in (0,1)$ is confusing me too) And this task has 15 points from 100)

Comment: Choose $N$ such that $\alpha+{1\over N} <1$. Show convergence. Then use a geometric series to guess the answer. (As an aside, just set $n=\infty$ and guess first. Then try to substantiate the guess.)

Comment: why have I to choose \alpha+{1\over N} <1 ?

Comment: So that $\sum_k(\alpha + { 1\over n})^k $ converges. This has nothing to do with $e$.